# Convert audio file to FLAC with ffmpeg?

Tags: macos, audio, ffmpeg, flac

can I convert one of this format to compatible **16000.0 Sample Rate FLAC** file?

```
kAudioFormatLinearPCM                   = 'lpcm',
kAudioFormatAppleIMA4                   = 'ima4',
kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC                    = 'aac ',
kAudioFormatMACE3                       = 'MAC3',
kAudioFormatMACE6                       = 'MAC6',
kAudioFormatULaw                        = 'ulaw',
kAudioFormatALaw                        = 'alaw',
kAudioFormatMPEGLayer1                  = '.mp1',
kAudioFormatMPEGLayer2                  = '.mp2',
kAudioFormatMPEGLayer3                  = '.mp3',
kAudioFormatAppleLossless               = 'alac'
```

I tried using ffmpeg

```
ffmpeg -i audio.xxx -acodec flac audio.flac
```

but result is

```
FFmpeg version CVS, Copyright (c) 2000-2004 Fabrice Bellard
Mac OSX universal build for ffmpegX
  configuration:  --enable-memalign-hack --enable-mp3lame --enable-gpl --disable-vhook --disable-ffplay --disable-ffserver --enable-a52 --enable-xvid --enable-faac --enable-faad --enable-amr_nb --enable-amr_wb --enable-pthreads --enable-x264 
  libavutil version: 49.0.0
  libavcodec version: 51.9.0
  libavformat version: 50.4.0
  built on Apr 15 2006 04:58:19, gcc: 4.0.1 (Apple Computer, Inc. build 5250)
Input #0, wsaud, from 'audio.alac':
  Duration: 00:00:03.8, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 199 kb/s
  Stream #0.0: Audio: adpcm_ima_ws, 24931 Hz, stereo, 199 kb/s
Unable for find a suitable output format for 'audio.flac'
```

I also installed flac codec for mac, but nothing...

I tried also use `convtoflac.sh` (from http://legroom.net/software/convtoflac) but result is similar.

Any idea to convert in flac?

Comment: Your version of ffmpeg has probably been built without FLAC support. Try `ffmpeg -formats | grep flac` and `ffmpeg -codecs | grep flac` to see.

Comment: Flac was present: `D A    flac`!

Comment: In both 'codecs' *and* 'formats'? Also, the `D` means "decoding". Without `E`ncoding support you're not going to make it work.

Comment: `ffmpeg -codecs | grep flac` won't work! I don't find any codec options....

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Forget the FFmpeg version that's included within ffmpegX – it's *really* old. Obviously it wasn't compiled with FLAC support.

You could:

- Download [a static build](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html) from the FFmpeg homepage. Just download the archive, extract it to some folder, then navigate to that folder and run it from there (`./ffmpeg`), or [add it to your `$PATH`](https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them).
- Install it using [Homebrew](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/installation), a package manager for OS X.
- Install it [from source](http://jungels.net/articles/ffmpeg-howto.html). Here's [a compilation guide for OS X](http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/MacOSXCompilationGuide).

Then, just try it again:

```
ffmpeg -i audio.xxx -c:a flac audio.flac
```

Comment: I reinstall theora and now it's ok, because link returns `No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/libtheora`. Thanks a lot man!

Comment: There's also a compilation guide [on the ffmpeg wiki](http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/MacOSXCompilationGuide), though I'm not really sure how to judge if it's better or worse than the ones you've already linked to.

Comment: @evilsoup Thanks. The guide didn't exist at the time of writing this answer, but it's definitely better than what I've found so far. Now I remember editing the Wiki page myself a few months ago.

Answer (score 2):

on linux 12.04 lts desktop this

```
ffmpeg -i audio.xxx -c:a flac audio.flac
```

has this error

"
Unrecognized option 'c:v'
Failed to set value 'flac' for option 'c:v'
"

this works without error

```
ffmpeg -i input.flv(mp4)  output.flac
```

Comment: Would adding `-vn` help?  It ought to tell ffmpeg to ignore the video stream.

Answer (score 1):

As slhck says, ffmpeg appears unable to recognise flac. It has to be told to look for it.

```
ffmpeg -i audio.xxx -f flac audio.flac
```

Comment: Why it reduce kb/s from 3000 to 1500?